# Make my custom Angular component required

Tags: angular, angular8

I wanna make a custom component in Angular is required to force the user to fill it.
I saw lots of solutions but using TypeScript code, is there any way to do that with HTML part without doing that with TS

for example:

```
<mycustom-component required ></mycustom-component>
```

### Update:

Below is my code I used mat-select with a custom search then I invoke the selector in a different place in my project, in some places I want it required and in another I want it not so I want the required property in the component selector not in the component it self

my code

**TS Code** :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild,AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Output, Input,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyCustomComponentDto,MyCustomComponentServiceProxy } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';
import { finalize,take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SharedService } from '@app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lkp-myCustomComponent',
  templateUrl: './lkp-myCustomComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lkp-myCustomComponent.component.css']
})
export class LkpMyCustomComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  /** list of myCustomComponents */
  public myCustomComponents: MyCustomComponentDto[] = [];

  /** control for the selected myCustomComponent for multi-selection */
  public myCustomComponentMultiCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  /** control for the MatSelect filter keyword multi-selection */
  public myCustomComponentMultiFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  /** list of myCustomComponents filtered by search keyword */
  public filteredMyCustomComponentsMulti: ReplaySubject<MyCustomComponentDto[]> = new ReplaySubject<MyCustomComponentDto[]>(1);

  @ViewChild('multiSelect', { static: true }) multiSelect: MatSelect;

  /** Subject that emits when the component has been destroyed. */
  protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

  myValue=0;

  constructor(public _myCustomComponentService:MyCustomComponentServiceProxy,
    public sharedService: SharedService) { 
     
  }

    async ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllMyCustomComponents(0);
      this.sharedService.fillMyCustomComponent =this.getAllMyCustomComponents.bind(this);

      
         
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   
    this.setInitialValue();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }

  /**
   * Sets the initial value after the filteredMyCustomComponents are loaded initially
   */
  protected setInitialValue() {
    this.filteredMyCustomComponentsMulti
      .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        // setting the compareWith property to a comparison function
        // triggers initializing the selection according to the initial value of
        // the form control (i.e. _initializeSelection())
        // this needs to be done after the filteredMyCustomComponents are loaded initially
        // and after the mat-option elements are available
        this.multiSelect.compareWith = (a: MyCustomComponentDto, b: MyCustomComponentDto) => a && b && a.id === b.id;
      });
  }

  protected filterMyCustomComponentsMulti() {
    
    if (!this.myCustomComponents) {
    
      return;
    }
    // get the search keyword
    let search = this.myCustomComponentMultiFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredMyCustomComponentsMulti.next(this.myCustomComponents.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    // filter the myCustomComponents
    this.filteredMyCustomComponentsMulti.next(
      this.myCustomComponents.filter(myCustomComponent => myCustomComponent.myCustomComponentArabicName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    );
  }



  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() selectedMyCustomComponent: any;
  actualChange(event){
    this.selectedMyCustomComponent = event.value;
    this.change.emit(this.selectedMyCustomComponent);

   
  }

getAllMyCustomComponents(myCustomComponentId:number){
  
    //return setTimeout(() => resolve("juraj2"), 2000);
   
  this._myCustomComponentService
            .getAllList()
            .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                  this.filteredMyCustomComponentsMulti.next(this.myCustomComponents.slice());
     
                  // listen for search field value changes
                  this.myCustomComponentMultiFilterCtrl.valueChanges
                    .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
                    .subscribe(() => {
                      this.filterMyCustomComponentsMulti();
                    });
                })
            )
            .subscribe( (result: any) => {


                this.myCustomComponents =  result.items;
           
                this.myCustomComponentMultiCtrl.setValue(result.items.find(x => x.id === myCustomComponentId));

            });
         
        
         // resolve("juraj2");
}

  
}
```

html part:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select name="MyCustomComponentList" [formControl]="MyCustomComponentMultiCtrl" [placeholder]="'MyCustomComponents' | localize"   [(ngModel)]="myValue"  #multiSelect (selectionChange)="actualChange($event)" required>
      <mat-option>
        <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="MyCustomComponentMultiFilterCtrl" placeholderLabel="search..."></ngx-mat-select-search>
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let MyCustomComponent of filteredMyCustomComponentsMulti | async" [value]="MyCustomComponent">
        {{MyCustomComponent.MyCustomComponentArabicName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Create your `input` with a `required` attribute in the html template.

Comment: @WillAlexander I've added it check my update

Comment: @Igor not working !